# How to Filter Detail Records For Master Detail Relationship Using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have coded my own objects representing my SQL tables and included the a foreign key relationship as below

```
[Table(Name = "tbl_employee")]
public class employee
{
    private EntitySet<workDay> _hours;
    public employee()
    {
        this._hours = new EntitySet<workDay>(OnDtlAdded, OnDtlremoved);
    }

    private void OnDtlAdded(workDay addedDtl) { addedDtl.Employee = this; }
    private void OnDtlremoved(workDay removedDtl) { removedDtl.Employee = null; }


    [Association(ThisKey = "employeeID", Storage = "_hours", OtherKey = "employeeID")]
    public EntitySet<workDay> Hours
    {
        get { return this._hours; }
        set { this._hours.Assign(value); }
    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public Int32 employeeID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public String nickName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public String idNumber { get; set; }

}
```

This all works perfectly and I can easily access the detail records from the Hours entityset. I would like to know if it is possible to automatically filter the details based on some criteria. The reason for this is that I display these items in a "master/detail" datagridview combination as follows:

```
var employees = from emp in db.Employees
                join empd in db.EmploymentDtls on emp.employeeID equals empd.employeeID
                where empd.termination == null && empd.deleted == 0 && emp.deleted == 0
                select emp;

dgvEmployees.DataSource = employees;
dgvHours.DataSource = employees;
dgvHours.DataMember = "Hours";
```

This allows me to display the hours for each employee without any further coding. I would like to achieve the same result but with the hours filtered to a certain date range and I was wondering if there was any way I could apply a default filter that could be applied when the details are loaded into the "detail" dataGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since abandoned this as I can find no way to implement it. It also seems that either nobody else knows how to do this or has looked at the question or that it is in fact not possible. Thanks to anyone who expended time or effort trying to figure it out.

I have since implemented filtering when a row in the master datagridview is selected.